# Need better explanation for Objectivec retain keyword

Tags: objective-c, xcode, retain

In Objectivec

MyClass*  ref1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
   MyClass*  re2 = ref1; 
   MyClass*  ref3 = [ref1 retain];

I'm wondering what is the total reference count after the this code

Comment: Read Apple's documentation about memory management. If you have problems, ask exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

+1 `MyClass* ref1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];` alloc set retain count to 1.
+0 `MyClass* ref2 = ref1` ref2 is weak reference to ref1.
+1 `MyClass* ref3 = [ref1 retain];` ref3 is strong reference to ref1.
Total references count is 2;

See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) for better understanding.